# Is permanent residence (unbefristete Niederlassungserlaubnis) in Germany counted as visa?

Tags: visa

For job application, I need to answer this question: Do you currently hold or have held a visa in the past 12 months for the location that the role is in?

The role is in Germany and I hold permanent residence (unbefristete Niederlassungserlaubnis) in Germany. Should I answer yes or no to this question?

Comment: [Expatriates.SE] would be the more appropriate place for this question.  Strictly speaking, the thing you have isn't a visa, but for many purposes it is equivalent to a visa, so the answer could be different in different contexts.  For your application, you want to make sure they know that you're authorized to work in Germany.  If answering "yes" to this question is the only way to include this information in the application, then you should answer yes.  Otherwise, you could answer no.